# Образ человека в русской диалектной фразеологии

Tags: фразеология, диалектология

Дорогие филологи, не судите строго, но в не могли бы вы мне помочь: курсовая работа под названием "Образ человека в русской диалектной фразеологии" подразумевает сплошную выборку слов из словаря Института Лингвистических Исследований РАН в разделе «человек». Да-да, я ничего такого не нахожу, или пользоваться надо словарем СРНГ Русских говоров? Если поняли о чем я, то прошу вас помочь. Как мне найти верный источник словаря? Или кэповский вопрос: какой вообще словарь? P.S.:у научника не допросишься

Comment: «Человек в русской диалектной фразеологии» — словарь, изданный в 2004 году в Москве ООО «ИТИ Технологии» . Авторы: Михаил Алексеенко, Ольга Литвинникова, Татьяна Белоусова.

Comment: @shampar спасибо

Comment: @shampar стоило бы оформить в виде ответа.

Comment: Я же за закрытие голосовал. Вопрос «одноразовый» и не по теме.

Comment: В научку сходите, Вам там всё дадут.

Answer (score 1):

Такие работы обычно пишут на материале определённой местности, иначе целая диссертация будет. Областных словарей очень много, например, «Архангельский областной словарь», «Живая речь Кольских поморов», «Новгородский областной словарь», «Областной словарь вятских говоров»,  «Псковский областной словарь с историческими данными», «Словарь вологодских говоров»,  Можно, думаю, воспользоваться и В. Далем, и вот этой книгой Мокиенко   http://bookre.org/reader?file=720020

Есть  специальные словари: «Материалы для идеографического словаря новгородских фразеологизмов», «Материалы для фразеологического словаря говоров Северного Прикамья», «Словарь псковских пословиц и поговорок», «Фразеологический словарь пермских говоров», «Фразеологический словарь русских говоров Нижней Печоры». 
Можно брать слова и из сводных диалектных словарей по тематическим группам «Физические данные и внешний вид», «Характер человека и его оценка», «Трудовая деятельность человека», «Материальное положение человека»; устойчивые сочетания, описывающие физические данные и внешний вид человека, его речь и эмоциональное состояние, «Интеллект и психика», «Отношение к алкоголю» и др.

Не знаю, какие требования к Вашей работе, но обычно тематическими словарями типа «Человек в русской диалектной фразеологии» Алексеенко и др. пользоваться не разрешают, там же готовые сведения, а Вы сами должны эти единицы описать, привести синонимы.